# Sample clause using Group by and Having clauses

Tags: oracle

I am trying to using Sample clause using Group by and Having clauses.
My requirement is getting a Company ID which has only one record, I have tried many ways below is one of the methods I have tried.

```
With TESTA AS(
select TA.COMPANY_ID from(
select t1.COMPANY_ID from Table11 t1
where t1.COMPANY_ID in (select t2.COMPANY_ID from Table22 t2) 
group by t1.COMPANY_ID having count(t1.COMPANY_ID)=1)TA )
select * FROM TESTA Sample(1);
```

When I execute the above query, It is throwing the below error.

> ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT,
>   GROUP BY, etc.
>   01446. 00000 -  "cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc."
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

But, When I execute the below query, I am getting the results but it is not satisfying my requirement.

```
select COMPANY_ID from Table11  Sample(10) 
where COMPANY_ID in (select company_id from Table22 )
Group by COMPANY_ID HAVING Count(COMPANY_ID)=1
```

It is executing all the possible records, can someone help me on this, please.

Comment: Why do you need to SAMPLE?. What's wrong with the output of your second query without sample?

Comment: @KaushikNayak it is taking a lot of time to execute the query, moreover, I need only one record from the result, The above query is not satisfying the condition Having count(COMPANY_ID)=1; The result is fetching all the records.

Comment: Are you saying that you just want to limit your results to 1 row? Why not use `where rownum=1` (or `fetch first 1 row only` if you're on 12c)?